# WordPress Page Reload Takes forever during theme development

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

OK, I'm hacking my way through my first theme (while reading Prof. WP Design & Development 2nd Ed.) and ....

EVERY TIME I change -for example- a p tag or a div tag or a css rule, when I then go to reload the page to see changes ... I....wait....and....wait.... for the dang page to reload!?!

I'm seeing "cache issue", but I'm unsure of exactly what that means, so I'm not sure that IS my problem.

IF this is a cache issue, can someone please explain exactly *what is going on under the hood* during the reload? And just what I can do about it?

Can someone break this down a bit for the noobs. :)

thanks,
sleeper

Comment: so what does your firebug console say about it? specifically your Net panel

Comment: Not exactly sure what your loking for, but I did notice that my blog page (the page I made the changes on ..ie. index.php) took 3.16 seconds (in Chrome) and then all other resources loaded.

Comment: also, the page load takes far longer. Up to 20 seconds in some cases.

Comment: Just to test, I opened the page in FF and it loaded right away. I made ONE CHANGE to a CSS rule and ...I ....wait ....again. This is maddening.

Comment: FF Net Panel is showing that the images are taking the longest (im using Theme Unit Test Data). DO I need to import the images?

Comment: Is it a web based installation or a local installation? On a web based installation there are many other things that can screw up.
The cache issue can be caused by a caching plugin or a server cache. Or a proxy cache. Or a browser cache. Or a browser plugin. Or a programm installed on your computer.

Comment: Dang! That's a lotta Cache! Im on Win7/64 Wamp Stack, (Local).

Comment: If you do not downloaded the images, it will naturally take a long time to load the images from the web. The server where the images are stored is not very fast.
And it can depend on your WAMPPP settings. My XAMPP installation (laptop) takes up to 10 seconds to load a page at the first time. A reload take 1-5 seconds. I think it is a problem with your WAMPP settings. Try something like [Instant WordPress](http://www.instantwp.com/), maybe it is a bit faster.

Comment: I disabled my plugins and no wait. I systematically activated each plugin (retesting each time) and now I cannot seem to recreate the wait. MUST be the cache @Ralf912 spoke of.

Comment: @Ralf912 Actually it appears I did download the images. So that's not it. Again, after de/re-activating plugins the wait is gone.

Comment: You deactivate all plugins and reactivate all plugins one by one. And the error occurs again or not? Or did the error/waiting time occurs only after a while?
If the problem is gone after deactivating all plugins, it seems it is caused by a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above, it seems the problem is caused by a plugin. You can try to search for the error message (cache issue?) within the plugin files. Some editors and IDEs have a function "file search" which searches in every file. E.g. in Notepadd++ you can do a file search by hitting [ctrl]+[f].

If you found the error message, deactivate the plugin and install an alternative plugin.

Comment: Yup. It's a plugin. Now my admin is doing the same craziness. Doing a fresh install. I'm looking into ways to capture error messages to a log file. Saw a post on it somewhere. trying to find it.